# Proving that a system of equalities and inequalities is inconsistent (Vol. 3)

Tags: inequality

I am studying sign pattern matrices and this is (hopefully!) the last of the systems that I have to prove inconsistent.

Prove that the system

$$\begin{cases} 
a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i>0 \\
-a+e-i=0 \\
-ae+ai+bd-ei+fh=0 \\
aei−hfa-bdi−gbf=0 \\
\end{cases}$$

is inconsistent.

I tried using some previously acquired techniques (such as factoring, or multiplying an equality and adding it to another equality) that worked for many families of such systems, but nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After substituting $e=a+i$ the system becomes
$$-a^2+bd-ai-i^2+fh=0\iff a^2+ai+i^2=bd+hf\\
a^2i+ai^2=hfa+bdi+gbf>hfa+bdi$$
But
\begin{align*}a^2i+ai^2<&a(a^2+ai+i^2)=a(bd+hf)\le hfa+bdi &\text{if }a\le i\\
<&i(a^2+ai+i^2)=i(bd+hf)\le hfa+bdi &\text{if }a\ge i\end{align*}

Comment: Clever solution! This actually resolves my problem, which is that a and i are not comparable just based on the given. So you also did not find a solution that does not consider cases?

Comment: You could say $a^2i+ai^2<\min(a,i)\cdot(a^2+ai+i^2)=\min(a,i)\cdot(bd+hf)\le hfa+bdi$, but that's really just hiding it by combining the cases.