# Proving that a system of equalities and inequalities is inconsistent (Vol. 4)

Tags: inequality

I am studying sign pattern matrices and I have to prove this statement.

Prove that the system

$$\begin{cases} 
a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i>0 \\
-a+e-i>0 \\
-ae+ai+bd-ei+fh>0 \\
aei−hfa-bdi−gbf>0 \\
\end{cases}$$

is inconsistent.

I tried using some previously acquired techniques (such as factoring, or multiplying an equality and adding it to another equality) that worked for many families of such systems, but I have  only proven it for the case when $i\leq a$. Here is what I have so far.

From the first inequality, we get

$$e > a+i \Rightarrow e>a. (*)$$

Multiplying the second inequality by $i$ and adding it to the third gives

$$a i^2 -e i^2 + fhi - hfa -gbf = i^2 (a-e) + fh(i-a) -gbf > 0.$$

But $a-e$ is negative by $(*)$, and $i-a \leq 0$ if $i \leq a$. This leads to a contradiction.

This [elegant approach by user2345215](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116334/proving-that-a-system-of-equalities-and-inequalities-is-inconsistent-vol-3?answertab=oldest#tab-top) works if > is replaced by =, but it cannot be generalized to work here.
How do I prove this if $a>i$? Maybe a radically different approach is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem. You've already proven it when $i\le a$ and the $i\ge a$ situation is symmetric and also gives a contradiction:
$$0<a(-ae+ai+bd-ei+fh)+aei-hfa-bdi-gbf=a^2(i-e)+bd(a-i)-gbf$$

Comment: Oh I get it now. So multiply the second by $a$ instead of $i$ to prove it for $i\leq a.$ Thanks! I hope this works for all the remaining cases I am working on (e.g., first inequality is positive and second is 0; first is 0 and second is positive; etc.).

Comment: @MarkLao You could also say that without loss of generality (WLOG), $i\ge a$ because if not, you can set $a'=i, i'=a, h'=d, d'=h, b'=f, f'=b$ (i.e. switching $a\leftrightarrow i, d\leftrightarrow h, b\leftrightarrow f$) and the system becomes exactly the same. So there's no need for doing the same argument again as you can reuse the $i\le a$ case.

Comment: That's a really nice observation! I have another question: As I have stated in the question, I have already proven similar problems for several families of such inequalities. This is the only family that requires a relatively long solution, i.e., taking cases. Do you think there is a more concise solution?